# use a different sidebar on the single.php of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use a different sidebar for a specific post category in wordpress

I am using a plugin called `simple page sidebars` where you can register new sidebars and assign them to pages.. Now I need to use such a sidebar (which I can configure in the widget area) in the `single.php` template if a specific category is selected.

Any hint? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try open your single.php and/or page.php and find the following code:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Replace the above code with this:

```
<?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true);
get_sidebar($sidebar);
?>
```

Comment: in this case it should't show the default sidebar but the sidebar "sidebar" instead right? ... still shows the normal sidebar though